# jQuery not working for dynamically created input field

Tags: jquery, html, forms, input

I have script, that on press of Enter on keyboard hides $this input and generates span with value of that field to display.

```
    $('.work_experience .achievements').on('keypress','input', function(event){
    if (!$(this).val() && event.which == 13 ) {
        alert('Input something');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var value = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().append('<span><i class="fa fa-times"></i> ' + value + '</span><input type="text" class="form-control input-xs" placeholder="I did" autofocus>');
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
        $('.achievements input:last-child').focus();
    }
});
```

It works. But then I have button, clicking on which generates new input field. And on that, newly created input, script doesn't work anymore. Help is appreciated.

**PS** Script adding new set of fields

```
    $('.form_fields').on('click','#add_work', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var field_set = '<div class="form-group work_experience">'+                            
                    '<input type="text" class="form-control input-m" id="company_name" placeholder="Company name">'+
                    '<input type="text" class="form-control input-m" id="company_place" placeholder="Company location">'+
                    '<input type="text" class="form-control input-m" id="work_period_start" placeholder="Beginnig">'+
                    '<input type="text" class="form-control input-m" id="work_period_end" placeholder="End">'+
                    '<label><input type="checkbox"> Currently</label>'+
                    '<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Write a few sentences about that company"></textarea>'+
                    '<input type="text" class="form-control input-m" placeholder="Your position">'+
                    '<label><strong>Achievements</strong></label>'+
                    '<div class="achievements">'+
                    '<input type="text" class="form-control input-xs" placeholder="I did">'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>';
    $(this).prev().after(field_set);
});
```

Comment: jquery version you are using ?

Comment: because you append it to `$(this).parent()`, but the delegated handlers are attached to `$(this)` and not to its parent. therefore the newly added inputs are placed outside of the handler's monitored scope

Comment: @Banana could you please elaborate a bit, thank you

Comment: @Elangovan no errors in console

Comment: @SergeyDubovik yes, i will post it as an answer because its long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event delegation for dynamically created dom

```
 $(document).on('keypress','input','.form-control',function(e){

     e.stopPropagation(); // stop the bubbling  if it is there 
     alert("cal");
    // do your work

    });
```

Note : you were  created dom element is   div  `<div class="form-group work_experience">'+`   ,it is `not input` field

Answer (score 0):

try
change from

```
$('.work_experience .achievements').on('keypress','input', function(event)
```

to

```
$('.work_experience .achievements').live('keypress','input', function(event)
```